# Github personal access token integration in IBM

Tags: github, token, ibm-watson, personal-access-token

the Github personal access token has changed its format and it is not being recognized by the IBM Cloud Pak for Data third party integration connection Github token prompt

I generate New personal access token (classic) fromm Github, checking the boxes for repo and gist.

I get a token that looks like this: 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

and input that in IBM Cloud Pak for Data > Services & Integration > third party > Connect

and it keeps coming back as invalid token. No matter how many times I try and even if I remove "ghp_"

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhyD5.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEMLd.png)